# Create new foreign key in form

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-autocomplete-light

I'm using django autocomplete_light and have two models connected via one-to-many relationship. Model A has a ForeignKey field TAG to model B. It all works, but I can only select the existing Tag, it is not possible to automatically add new Tag, even though it is possible to freely type in the box.

How can I "intercept" validation and create the suitable database entry for tag in time?

Answer (score 1):

You could use an [add another popup](http://django-autocomplete-light.readthedocs.org/en/latest/addanother.html) like in django admin.

Here's a [live example](http://jpic.pythonanywhere.com/non_admin_add_another/widget/add/) using [this code](https://github.com/yourlabs/django-autocomplete-light/tree/master/test_project/non_admin_add_another). The design is not very very good but it demonstrates the point.